# how to make the checkboxgroupinput color-coded in Shiny

Tags: fonts, colors, shiny, controls

It's a bit open-minded. I did some research with google, but no hit at all.

I have a shiny project, in which I use a checkboxGroupInput in sidepanel, sth like this:

> ```
>    checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variable:",
>                      choices = names ,selected = names
>     )
> ```

where the 'names' is a character vector.

I include legend (different colors for different names) in a chart in main panel. Now I am thinking to change the text colors of the names (one color for each name) in sidepanel so that I can get rid of the legend in the chart.

Does anyone know how to do it?  thanks so much.

Comment: You should try to avoid using existing R function names like `names` to store your content. Prefer using `my_names` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. This is not my code, I just copied a simpler code as an example. Would you please take a look at my question posted under your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this directly in shiny, BUT you can analyse the HTML built by shiny in the browser inspector/

```
<div id="variable" class="form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" for="variable">Variable:</label>
  <div class="shiny-options-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="variable" value="1" checked="checked"/>
        <span>one</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="variable" value="2" checked="checked"/>
        <span>two</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="variable" value="3"/>
        <span>three</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can then recreate it using `renderUI`:

```
my_checkboxGroupInput <- function(variable, label, choices, selected, colors){
  choices_names <- choices
  if(length(names(choices))>0) my_names <- names(choices)
  div(id=variable,class="form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container shiny-bound-input",
    HTML(paste0('<label class="control-label" for="',variable,'">',label,'</label>')),
    div( class="shiny-options-group",
      HTML(paste0('<div class="checkbox" style="color:', colors,'">',
                    '<label>',
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="', variable, 
                        '" value="', choices, 
                        '"', ifelse(choices %in% selected, 'checked="checked"', ''), 
                    '/>',
                    '<span>', choices_names,'</span>',
                    '</label>',
                  '</div>', collapse = " "))
      )
    )
}

library(shiny)
my_names <- c('one'=1,'two'=2,'three'=3)
my_selected <- c(1,2)
my_colors <-c('blue','red','green')
shinyApp(
  ui=fluidPage(uiOutput("my_cbgi")),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$my_cbgi <- renderUI(my_checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variable:",
                                                     choices = my_names,
                                                     selected=my_selected, 
                                                     colors=my_colors))
    }
  )
```

#### Edit

In order to display in color only selected items, you need to slightly modify the function and use a reactiveValue to map input$variable as the current selection, like this:

```
my_checkboxGroupInput <- function(variable, label,choices, selected, colors){
  my_names <- choices
  if(length(names(choices))>0) my_names <- names(choices)
  div(id=variable,class="form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container shiny-bound-input",
    HTML(paste0('<label class="control-label" for="',variable,'">',label,'</label>')),
    div( class="shiny-options-group",
      HTML(paste0('<div class="checkbox">',
                    '<label>',
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="', variable, 
                        '" value="', choices, 
                        '"', ifelse(choices %in% selected, 'checked="checked"', ''), 
                    '/>',
                    '<span ', ifelse(choices %in% selected, paste0('style="color:', colors,'"'),''), '>',my_names,'</span>',
                    '</label>',
                  '</div>', collapse = " "))
      )
    )
}

my_names <- c('one'=1,'two'=2,'three'=3)
my_selected <- c(1,2)
my_colors <-c('blue','red','green')
shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(uiOutput("my_cbgi")),
         server = function(input, output, session) {
           my <- reactiveValues(selected=my_selected)
           observeEvent(input$variable,{my$selected <- input$variable})
           output$my_cbgi <- renderUI(my_checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variable:",
                                                            choices = my_names, 
                                                            selected=my$selected,
                                                            colors=my_colors))
         })
```

Comment: Thanks for coding so much to explain. Very helpful. Let me modify my project with your hints.

Comment: Thanks, HubertL, your way works great.
Now, I have a more advanced question:
If I ONLY want the selected checkboxes to be color coded, which means, when I uncheck one, the font color changes dynamically to default (black), and vice versa. 
I tried hard but didn't find any interactive way to make this happen.

Comment: I don't quite follow your logic from the last update.  You called the function "my_checkboxGroupInput" in server session, but 1) the checkboxes are obviously inputs 2)the input variable ("my$selected <- input$variable") is obtained from an existing checkbox group, which I wanna control the font colors of. 



    ##### Here is my situation:  I called the function "my_checkboxGroupInput" in ui.R, and could not dynamically get the "variable" updated, so I could not use your logic properly.

Comment: It is quite common to built the ui in the server part when deeper control over the ui is needed

Comment: Great to know. I've never done this way b4.  Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: sorry, I always thought the last question was really the LAST one. Now I have one further question. Since I cannot post formatted code in the comment, I have to post them in another answer session. Please see about for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tags$style` for that:

```
lapply(1:length(names), function(x) {
   n <- length(names)
   col <- gplots::col2hex(rainbow(n)[x])
   css_col <- paste0("#variable div.checkbox:nth-child(",x,
                     ") span{color: ", col,";}")
   tags$style(type="text/css", css_col)
}),
checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variable:",
                   choices = names, selected = names)
```

Comment: Sorry, I tested this code in one of my apps and forgot to change that (will edit that). `#filespar` was the id of my `checkboxGroupInput`. In your case would be `#variable`. Do indicate the id of the `checkboxGroupInput` else I fear all `checkboxGroupInput`s in your app will be colored following these `tag$style`s.

Answer (score 0):

@HubertL

Your final version works great. However, I wanna things more dynamic -- instead of assigning a color to a choice permanently, I prefer assigning first N colors to the N chosen item. Unfortunately, the code I customized does not work the way I want.

For example, I have 6 colors, and have all six variables chosen by default, when I de-check any one of (two, three, four, five), I assume the color ones after the de-checked will update properly.  let's say **('blue','red','green','purple','lemon','brown')** for **('one','two','three','four','five','six')**; when I de-check 'three', I wanna see ('blue','red','green','purple','lemon') for ('one','two','four','five','six'), but the actual color is *('blue','red','purple','lemon','blue')*.

here is the code I used for testing:

> my_names <- c('one','two','three','four','five','six')
>
> my_selected <- c('one','two','three','four','five','six')
>
> my_colors <-c('blue','red','green','purple','lemon','brown')
>
> shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(uiOutput("my_cbgi")),
>
> ```
>      server = function(input, output, session) {
>        my <- reactiveValues(selected=my_selected)
>        observeEvent(input$variable,{my$selected <- input$variable})
>        output$my_cbgi <- renderUI(my_checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variable:",
>                                                         choices = my_names, 
>                                                         selected=my$selected,
>                                                         colors=my_colors[1:length(my$selected)]))
>      })
> ```

Comment: You are not supposed to ask a question in an answer, make a new question instead

Comment: @HubertL  Sorry, I was not aware of this rule.

here is the new post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886018/shiny-checkboxgroupinput-dynamic-backgroud-color-control

Comment: Please delete this "answer"