# Problem with collapsing checkboxGroupInput in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a long list of choices in my checkboxGroupInput. Following this amazing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738392/collapsible-checkboxgroupinput-in-shiny), I could collapse my list of choices. But when the choices are expanded by clicking the more button, the background of the sidebar becomes red. How can I fix this?

When I remove the code below, the problem is solved but removing the code creates other problems around the background color in the navbar page. How can I keep the code below and solve the problem?

[image]

```
tags$style("
       .collapse  {background-color: #B61E2E; color:white}
       "),
```

Comment: in this case, you could replace `checkboxGroupInput` by `selectizeInput`

Comment: Thnaks. I would like to have the choices as a list in the shiny.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you supplied that red as the background-color in the css. Maybe you could match it to the grey you want for the rest of the sidebar. Or provide additional css to the sidebar to match the colors.
Note you can run the code for just one shiny object to see how it translates to html--- this can be helpful getting class names so you can provide additional css in a custom style sheet or through more tags. See here for example: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html